# Static allocation and placement new result in null pointer dereference

Tags: c++11, constructor, initialization, virtual-inheritance, placement-new

I am working on an embedded platform where heap allocation is discouraged. I also have circular dependencies during construction. Given these constraints my team designed a static allocator class which is used to allocate memory in the `.bss` section and then construct the object in a deferred fashion.

The issue we face is during the deferred construction the compiler generated code tries to reference data in the statically allocated memory that hasn't been constructed yet - the data are zero on our platform when unconstructed - which causes a null pointer dereference crashing the system.

The crashes can be resolved by reordering the construction order of the classes. Unfortunately I haven't been able to create a minimum reproduction of the issue. Additionally the problem gets worse and harder to manage when virtual inheritance is involved.

We have experienced the issue targeting armclang and visual studio compilers so it seems like we are likely doing something out of the C++ specification.

Static Allocator Code:

```
template <class UnderlyingType, typename... Args>
class StaticAllocator
{
private:
    typedef std::uint64_t BaseDataType;

    // Define a tuple of the variadic template parameters with the references removed
    using TupleWithRefsRemoved = std::tuple<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...>;

    // A function that strips return the ref-less template arguments
    template <typename... T>
    TupleWithRefsRemoved removeRefsFromTupleMembers(std::tuple<T...> const& t)
    {
        return TupleWithRefsRemoved{ t };
    }

public:
    StaticAllocator()
    {
        const auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<UnderlyingType *>(&m_underlyingData);
        assert(ptr != nullptr);
    }

    virtual StaticAllocator* clone() const
    {
        return new StaticAllocator<UnderlyingType, Args...>(*this);
    }

    UnderlyingType *getPtr()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<UnderlyingType *>(&m_underlyingData);
    }

    const UnderlyingType *getPtr() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const UnderlyingType *>(&m_underlyingData);
    }

    UnderlyingType *operator->()
    {
        return getPtr();
    }

    const UnderlyingType *operator->() const
    {
        return getPtr();
    }

    UnderlyingType &operator*()
    {
        return *getPtr();
    }

    const UnderlyingType &operator*() const
    {
        return *getPtr();
    }

    operator UnderlyingType *()
    {
        return getPtr();
    }

    operator const UnderlyingType *() const
    {
        return getPtr();
    }

    void construct(Args... args)
    {
        _construct(TupleWithRefsRemoved(args...), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
    }

    void destroy()
    {
        const auto ptr = getPtr();
        if (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            ptr->~T();
        }
    }

private:
    BaseDataType m_underlyingData[(sizeof(UnderlyingType) + sizeof(BaseDataType) - 1) / sizeof(BaseDataType)];

    // A function that unpacks the tuple of arguments, and constructs them
    template <std::size_t... T>
    void _construct(const std::tuple<Args...>& args, std::index_sequence<T...>)
    {
        new (m_underlyingData) UnderlyingType(std::get<T>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Simple Usage Example:

```
class InterfaceA
{
    // Interface functions here
}

class InterfaceB
{
    // Interface functions here
}


class ObjectA : public virtual InterfaceA
{
public:
    ObjectA(InterfaceB* intrB) : m_intrB(intrB) {}

private:
    InterfaceB* m_intrB;
};

class ObjectB : public virtual InterfaceB
{
public:
    ObjectB(InterfaceA* intrA) : m_intrA(intrA) {}

private:
    InterfaceA* m_intrA;
}

StaticAllocator<ObjectA, InterfaceB*> objectAStorage;
StaticAllocator<ObjectB, InterfaceA*> objectBStorage;

// Crashes happen in this function, there are many more objects in our real
// system and the order of the objects effects if the crash occurs.
void initialize_objects()
{
    auto objA = objectAStorage.getPtr();
    auto objB = objectBStorage.getPtr();

    objectAStorage.construct(objB);
    objectBStorage.construct(objA);
}
```

Comment: While upcast to a non-virtual base class is merely a pointer adjustment, upcast to a virtual base class uses run-time data structures initialized by the most derived class' constructor, as the relative location of that base class varies with the class hierarchy. You are doing it with a pointer pointing to uninitialized memory, whereby your program exhibits undefined behavior. I can dig up chapter and verse if necessary.

Comment: Is there a "correct" way of statically allocating and constructing inherited classes? When you say we are "doing it with a pointer pointing to uninitialized memory" which pointer are you talking about? The `objA` and `objB` pointers, or the memory pointed to by `m_underlyingData` in `StaticAllocator`?

Comment: The problem is not with allocating and constructing, but with the fact that you have circular dependency. I don't see how you can properly construct these two objects with plain old `new` either.

Comment: Specifically, `objectAStorage.construct(objB)` performs a cast from `ObjectB*` to `InterfaceB*`, which requires that `objB` point to a fully constructed object of type `ObjectB`. In reality, it points to uninitialized memory.

Comment: Is `getPtr()` ever null?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated32 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways" ... "The program has undefined behavior if:" ... "the pointer is used as the operand of a static_­cast ([expr.static.cast]), except when the conversion is to pointer to cv void"

Comment: So **is `static_cast` to a non virtual base class** UB according [basic.life/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6)?

Comment: You could make your question more simple by dropping the static buffer and all the static stuff which is merely an optimisation and a distraction. Just use `malloc`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer describes the problem happening at run time, using the example of GCC. Other compilers will generate different code with similar problem as your code has an inherent  the issue of lack of initialization.

Without the avoidance of dynamic memory allocation for efficiency purpose, without the generic approach, without templates, with every step decomposed, your code really boils down to:

```
class InterfaceA {};

class InterfaceB {};

class ObjectA : public virtual InterfaceA {
 public:
  ObjectA(InterfaceB *intrB) : m_intrB(intrB) {}

 private:
  InterfaceB *m_intrB;
};

class ObjectB : public virtual InterfaceB {
 public:
  ObjectB(InterfaceA *intrA) : m_intrA(intrA) {}

 private:
  InterfaceA *m_intrA;
};

#include <new>

void simple_init() {
  void *ObjectA_mem = operator new(sizeof(ObjectA));
  void *ObjectB_mem = operator new(sizeof(ObjectB));
  ObjectA *premature_ObjectA = static_cast<ObjectA *>(ObjectA_mem);  // still not constructed
  ObjectB *premature_ObjectB = static_cast<ObjectB *>(ObjectB_mem);
  InterfaceA *ia = premature_ObjectA;  // derived-to-base conversion
  InterfaceB *ib = premature_ObjectB;
  new (ObjectA_mem) ObjectA(ib);
  new (ObjectB_mem) ObjectB(ia);
}
```

For maximum compiled code readability, let's write that with global variables instead:

```
void *ObjectA_mem;
void *ObjectB_mem;
ObjectA *premature_ObjectA;
ObjectB *premature_ObjectB;
InterfaceA *ia;
InterfaceB *ib;

void simple_init() {
  ObjectA_mem = operator new(sizeof(ObjectA));
  ObjectB_mem = operator new(sizeof(ObjectB));
  premature_ObjectA = static_cast<ObjectA *>(ObjectA_mem);  // still not constructed
  premature_ObjectB = static_cast<ObjectB *>(ObjectB_mem);
  ia = premature_ObjectA;  // derived-to-base conversion
  ib = premature_ObjectB;
  new (ObjectA_mem) ObjectA(ib);
  new (ObjectB_mem) ObjectB(ia);
}
```

That [gives us a very nice assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/KyEroW). We can see that the statement:

```
  ia = premature_ObjectA;  // derived-to-base conversion
```

compiles to:

```
        movq    premature_ObjectA(%rip), %rax
        testq   %rax, %rax
        je      .L6
        movq    premature_ObjectA(%rip), %rdx
        movq    premature_ObjectA(%rip), %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        subq    $24, %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        jmp     .L7
.L6:
        movl    $0, %eax
.L7:
        movq    %rax, ia(%rip)
```

First we see that the (un-optimized) code tests for a null pointer, the equivalent of

```
if (premature_ObjectA == 0) 
  ia = 0;
else
  // real stuff
```

The real stuff being:

```
    movq    premature_ObjectA(%rip), %rdx
    movq    premature_ObjectA(%rip), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    subq    $24, %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rax, ia(%rip)
```

So a value pointed to by `premature_ObjectA` is dereferenced, interpreted as a pointer, decreased by 24, the resulting pointer is used to read a value, that value is added to the original pointer `premature_ObjectA`. Since the content of `premature_ObjectA` is uninitialized, that obviously cannot work.

What's happening is that the compiler is fetching the vptr (vtable pointer) to read the entry at -3 "quad" (3*8 = 24) from the level 0 (a vtable like a building can have negative floors, it just means that the 0th floor isn't the lowest floor):

```
vtable for ObjectA:
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for ObjectA
vtable for ObjectB:
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for ObjectB
```

The vtable (of each of these objects) *starts at its end*, after "typeinfo for ObjectA", as we can see inside compiled code for `ObjectA::ObjectA(InterfaceB*)`:

```
        movl    $vtable for ObjectA+24, %edx
...
        movq    %rdx, (%rax)
```

So during construction, the vptr is set to "floor 0" of the vtable which is before the first virtual function, at the end if there is no virtual function.

At floor -3 there is the beginning of the vtable:

```
vtable for ObjectA:
        .quad   0
```

The value 0 is for "`InterfaceA` is at offset 0 inside a complete `ObjectA` object".

The fine details of the vtable layout will be compiler dependent, the principles:

- initialization of the vptr hidden data member (and possibly multiple other hidden members) in the constructor
- using these hidden members during conversion to `InterfaceA` base class

remains the same.

*My explanation does not provide a fix:* we don't even know what kind of high level problem you have and why you use these constructor argument and mutually dependent classes.

**Knowing what these classes represent, we might be able to help more.**